# IE8 VERY Slow to load! Help

Tags: internet-explorer-8, performance

I've recently built a website from scratch which I'm very proud of (a new feat for me!) and have begun testing it in dreaded IE. I've noticed that in IE8 if I want to hover over any link it just takes a long time to do (upwards of 0.5seconds to recognize the mouse is over a link and to change to a 'click here' icon). It works 'fine' in IE6 and IE7.

When I take out 2 simple pictures (about 500KB and 100KB) the page seems to work fine. Why do these two pictures trip up IE8 so badly, yet every other browser can handle pictures of this size just fine? What can I do to fix it?

-Karl

Comment: The guys at http://doctype.com/ may be able to help more.

Comment: Oh cool I'll give that a go as well, thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

Web images should be as small as possible, if there's not a real reason why those two pictures are so large, I'd reduce them. For examples check out the images in most successful web-sites..

Comment: I agree, I need to work on getting them smaller. BUT...in fooling around with different pictures, I've put in 2 100KB pictures in place of the 500KB, and IE8 STILL acts poorly! Why is IE8 treating my pictures different than any other browser out there (including other IEs)?

Comment: IE uses a completely different rendering engine. Chrome/ Safari uses Webkit, Firefox uses Gekko (I think) and IE have their own.

Comment: So IE8 uses a different rendering engine than IE6 and 7 as well? Because those work just fine =( Also, any ideas of what I should try in order to fix this problem??

Comment: Hey, yes I'm afraid so - IE8 uses a different version of the IE rendering engine. What type of image are you using? PNG? JPG?

Comment: I am using JPGs.